# Error message pops up when trying to use connection.play

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I am trying to use the function connection.play to play a local file, an error pops up said

TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int

var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};var moduleOverrides={};var key;for(key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}Module["arguments"]=[];Module["thisProgram"]="./this.program";Module["quit"]=function(status,toThrow){throw toThrow};Module["preRun"]=[];Module["postRun"]=[];var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVguments"]=[];Module["tg";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKEWORKER=false;var ENVIRR;var scriptDirectory="";function locateFile(path){if(Module["locateFile"]){                                                                                                  unction";ENVIRONMENT_H
abort(TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.

Why would this error pop up?

here's my code

```
message.member.voice.channel.join().then(connection=>{
  const dispatcher = connection.play('./'+args[1]+'.mp3', { volume: 0.5 });     
  dispatcher.on("end", end => {message.member.voice.channel.leave()});             
}).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: Could you please provide the rest of the error? That information is be useful to track down where the error is happening.

Comment: i've edited the error

Comment: It's weird that I change nothing and it suddenly worked when I am trying to run the command again